# Cant run PHP files after installing wampserver.. Although i can run the localhost,etc

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, wampserver

I've installed wampserver. Its installed and I can see its icon on the tray. But I cannot open a simple PHP file. I saved the file in  C:\wamp\www and I'm trying to open it by using the following URL in the browser using localhost. But I'm getting Error 404 File not found on the server! I tried restarting the PC and the wampserver services but to no avail. Please help me. I'm a newbie. Please help me.

Comment: sir you need to call it like http://localhost/abc.php , wherein abc.php is a file saved in c:\wamp\www folder

Comment: 1) use like localhost/urfile.php
and once check your installation directory . may be the www folder in c drive is old dir and you installed new one in some other dir.

Comment: Actually I had installed an older version then re-installed a newer version in a new directory. And so now the problem is resolved. Thank you so much everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write the correct URL Path ? If you drop the file into e.g :

```
C:/Wamp/www/file.php
```

Then you must write the URL into this form:

```
http://localhost/file.php
```

Note: 404 error is an http error , means the resources you are trying to reach is not exist !

Comment: Actually I had installed an older version then re-installed a newer version in a new directory. And so now the problem is resolved. Thank you so much everyone.